# Print exact two decimal numbers in table?

Tags: r, function, decimal

Following script is used to print a table with unit root test results. You can try the code yourself.

```
library(vars)
Canada = data.frame(Canada)
library(urca)
library(stargazer)
library(dplyr)

table_adf = function(DF, ...){
  var_list = as.list(unlist(list(...)))
  if(length(var_list) == 0){
    subset = DF
    var_list = as.list(names(DF))
  }else{
    subset = select_(DF, .dots = var_list)
  }

  tests = lapply(subset, function(x, y){
    out1 = ur.df(x, type = "drift", selectlags = "BIC")
    out2 = ur.df(x, type = "trend", selectlags = "BIC")
    out3 = ur.pp(x, type = "Z-tau", model = "const", lags = "short")
    out4 = ur.pp(x, type = "Z-tau", model = "trend", lags = "short")
    out5 = ur.kpss(x, type = "mu", lags = "short")
    out6 = ur.kpss(x, type = "tau", lags = "short")
    return(list(out1, out2, out3, out4, out5, out6))
  })

  est_df = lapply(tests, function(x){
    data.frame(ADF_constant = x[[1]]@teststat[1],
               ADF_trend = x[[2]]@teststat[1],
               PP_const = x[[3]]@teststat[1],
               PP_trend = x[[4]]@teststat[1],
               KPSS_const = x[[5]]@teststat[1],
               KPSS_trend = x[[6]]@teststat[1])
  })

  est_table = do.call(rbind, est_df)
  est_table = round(est_table, 2)
  critical_vals = data.frame(tests[[1]][[1]]@cval[1,], 
                             tests[[1]][[2]]@cval[1,],
                             tests[[1]][[3]]@cval[1,],
                             tests[[1]][[4]]@cval[1,],
                             tests[[1]][[5]]@cval[1,-1],
                             tests[[1]][[6]]@cval[1,-1])

  est_table[, 1:4] = Map(function(x, y){
    ifelse(x < y[1], paste(x, "0.01"), 
           ifelse(x < y[2], paste(x, "0.05"),
                  ifelse(x < y[3], paste(x, "0.10"), paste(x, ""))))
  }, est_table[, 1:4], critical_vals[, 1:4]) %>% data.frame(row.names = unlist(var_list))

  est_table[, 5:6] = Map(function(x, y){
    ifelse(x > y[3], paste(x, "0.01"),
           ifelse(x > y[2], paste(x, "0.02"),
                  ifelse(x > y[1], paste(x, "0.05"), paste(x, ""))))
  }, est_table[, 5:6], critical_vals[, 5:6]) %>% data.frame(row.names = unlist(var_list))

  stargazer(est_table, type = "text", summary = FALSE)
}

table_adf(Canada, "e", "prod", "rw", "U")
```

**Output table:**

```
=====================================================================
     ADF_constant ADF_trend  PP_const  PP_trend KPSS_const KPSS_trend
---------------------------------------------------------------------
e        -0.3       -2.73      0.15     -1.62   2.05 0.01  0.17 0.05 
prod    -0.11       -2.02      0.26     -1.97   1.66 0.01  0.27 0.01 
rw    -4.37 0.01    -2.82   -5.62 0.01  -2.81   2.12 0.01  0.43 0.01 
U       -2.22       -2.47     -1.72     -1.96      0.23       0.14   
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see in the example, the first value is displayed as `-0.3` instead of `-0.30`. How can I adjust the script, so that each test result is printed as a number with two decimals?

Comment: You should have done something with the original question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634643/r-function-to-print-table-with-stationarity-test-results/46637222#46637222.

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion is to define a new `paste` function. E.g

```
pasteFix <- function(x, signLev){
  ifelse(nchar(as.character(abs(x)))<4, 
  paste(paste(x, "0", sep=""),signLev),
  paste(x, signLev))
}
```

(`nchar<4` to account for the comma. `abs()` to remove `-`).
Then replace the old `paste` function in your `Map`

```
est_table[, 1:4] = Map(function(x, y){
   ifelse(x < y[1], pasteFix(x, "0.01"), 
       ifelse(x < y[2], pasteFix(x, "0.05"),
              ifelse(x < y[3], pasteFix(x, "0.10"), pasteFix(x, ""))))
}, est_table[, 1:4], critical_vals[, 1:4]) %>% data.frame(row.names = 
  unlist(var_list))

est_table[, 5:6] = Map(function(x, y){
  ifelse(x > y[3], pasteFix(x, "0.01"),
       ifelse(x > y[2], pasteFix(x, "0.02"),
              ifelse(x > y[1], pasteFix(x, "0.05"), pasteFix(x, ""))))
}, est_table[, 5:6], critical_vals[, 5:6]) %>% data.frame(row.names = 
 unlist(var_list))
```

Output is then

```
=====================================================================
     ADF_constant ADF_trend  PP_const  PP_trend KPSS_const KPSS_trend
---------------------------------------------------------------------
e       -0.30       -2.73      0.15     -1.62   2.05 0.01  0.17 0.05 
prod    -0.11       -2.02      0.26     -1.97   1.66 0.01  0.27 0.01 
rw    -4.37 0.01    -2.82   -5.62 0.01  -2.81   2.12 0.01  0.43 0.01 
U       -2.22       -2.47     -1.72     -1.96      0.23       0.14   
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried it with my code but the problem ist that this kind of formatting produces missing marks for the significance level. I wonder if there's any way to "just" print the test-statistics as two digits..

Comment: Ah, yeah. Forgot to add the significance level in the print if `nchar()<4`. Updated the `pasteFix` in the answer.